# How to config the path for the dynamic module of nginx to access?

Tags: c++, c, nginx

I tried googling but the results are answering how to assign the path to the module's implementation c code for nginx to compile a module.

My module will read/write files upon end-user's request, and my question is how to set the path so that my module will directly read/write in that directory.

I found that without extra settings, my module will read/write the folder I initiate nginx. For example, if I run `sudo nginx` where `pwd` is `/Users/me/html/data`, then the dynamic module will read/write files from `/Users/me/html/data`.

What would be the best practice to set the path to access data for my module?